# Context menu methods in shell extension aren't being used

Tags: c++, winapi, com, shell-extensions

I am trying to write a shell extension that adds a menu item to the context menu for all file types. The code for the extension (in its entirety) is located [here](https://github.com/nitroshare/nitroshare-desktop/tree/master/shell) but I'll include some of the relevant parts below as I describe the problem.

The `ContextMenu` class implements the [`IShellExtInit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775096(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`IContextMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776095(v=vs.85).aspx) interfaces:

```
class ContextMenu : public IShellExtInit, IContextMenu
{
public:

    // [...]

    // IShellExtInit methods
    STDMETHODIMP Initialize(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFolder,
                            IDataObject *pdtobj, HKEY hkeyProgID);

    // IContextMenu methods
    STDMETHODIMP GetCommandString(UINT_PTR idCmd, UINT uType, UINT *pReserved,
                                  LPSTR pszName, UINT cchMax);
    STDMETHODIMP InvokeCommand(LPCMINVOKECOMMANDINFO pici);
    STDMETHODIMP QueryContextMenu(HMENU hmenu, UINT indexMenu, UINT idCmdFirst,
                                  UINT idCmdLast, UINT uFlags);
}
```

All of the methods are rigged with `MessageBox()` calls to indicate when they are called. There is only one small problem — they are never called.

The extension includes another class that implements [`IClassFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694364(v=vs.85).aspx). The implementation for [`IClassFactory::CreateInstance()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682215(v=vs.85).aspx) is as follows:

```
STDMETHODIMP ClassFactory::CreateInstance(IUnknown *pUnkOuter, REFIID riid,
                                          LPVOID *ppvObject)
{
    if (pUnkOuter) {
        return CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION;
    }

    if (!ppvObject) {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    *ppvObject = NULL;

    ContextMenu *contextMenu = new ContextMenu;
    HRESULT hResult = contextMenu->QueryInterface(riid, ppvObject);
    contextMenu->Release();
    return hResult;
}
```

I can confirm that this method is being called and I can also confirm that `ContextMenu::QueryInterface()` is then being called with `riid` set to `IID_IContextMenu`.

However, nothing happens after that. None of the `IContextMenu` methods are called. Neither is [`IShellExtInit::Initialize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775094(v=vs.85).aspx). Why is this happening?

#### Test Environment

- Visual Studio 2013 Express
- Windows 7 Home Premium x64

---

**Edit:** I completely forgot to describe how the extension is being registered. The [`DllRegisterServer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682162(v=vs.85).aspx) function creates the following registry keys/values and checks the error codes to confirm that they are created:

- **Key:** `HKCR\CLSID\{CLSID}`, **Value:** `NULL`, **Data:** `NitroShellExt`
- **Key:** `HKCR\CLSID\{CLSID}\InprocServer32`, **Value:** `NULL`, **Data:** `[path to DLL]`
- **Key:** `HKCR\CLSID\{CLSID}\InprocServer32`, **Value:** `ThreadingModel`, **Data:** `Apartment`
- **Key:** `HKCR\*\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\NitroShellExt`, **Value:** `NULL`, **Data:** `{CLSID}`
- **Key:** `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Approved`, **Value:** `{CLSID}`, **Data:** `NitroShare Context Menu`

...where `{CLSID}` is `{52A10783-C811-4C45-9A3D-221A962C8640}`. I then use `regsvr32` to register the extension and `regedit` to confirm that the keys/values do indeed exist.

Comment: And how exactly are you registering this extension in the Registry? That plays a very important part in how it gets invoked at runtime. You likely are not registering it correctly, which would explain why the Shell is not trying to initialize it

Comment: @RemyLebeau good idea - I updated the question.

Comment: At first glance, it looks OK. But don't write to HKCR directly  use  `HKLM\Software\Classes` for all users, or `HKCU\Software\Classes` for the current user. See [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475.aspx) and [Merged View of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724498.aspx) for more details. Also, are you calling `SHChangeNotify()` after (un)registering the extension? Does the handler work after a reboot?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I switched to HKLM as suggested and yes, I am calling `SHChangeNotify()`. I tried rebooting and lo and belhold - `IShellExtInit::Initialize()` gets called! I have no idea why merely restarting `explorer.exe` wasn't enough to get this working. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Maybe you weren't calling `SHChangeNotify()` correctly.  Who knows.  You didn't show any of your registration code.